# How to smooth this Figure in Python with from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

Tags: python, scipy, smoothing

There is a plot which I want to make smooth for better representation. I tried `scipy.interpolate`, however it produced this error:

> raise ValueError("Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.")
> ValueError: Expect x to be a 1-D sorted array_like.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy import interpolate
    from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

    startnm = 550
    endnm = 700
    y = np.empty((10,))

    for aci in range(0, 91, 10):

    data = pd.read_csv(f".\\30mg-ml-PSQD-withZNO-12-nov-21\\{aci}.txt",
                       delimiter="\t") .to_numpy()[:, [0, 1]]
    print(type(data[0, 0]))
    starti, endi = 0, 0
    for i in range(len(data[:, 0])):
        if startnm < float(data[i, 0]) and starti == 0:
            starti = i
        elif endnm < float(data[i, 0]) and endi == 0:
            endi = i
            break

    y[aci//10] = np.sum(data[starti:endi, 1])


    theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 19)

    output = []
    x = []
    for i in range(10):
    temp0 = y[i]
    output.append(temp0*np.cos(theta[i])/y.max())
    x.append(temp0*np.sin(theta[i])/y.max())
    pass

    print(output)
    print(x)


    plt.title("title")
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")

    plt.plot(x, output,"--")
    plt.plot(-np.array(x), output, "--")

    x = np.sin(theta)*np.cos(theta)
    y = np.cos(theta)*np.cos(theta)


    plt.plot(x, y, "r")
    plt.grid(color = 'green', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.5)

 

    plt.show()
```

I want to smooth this graph as much as possible. How can I do it?

[image: I want to make the dashed lines as smooth as possible]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error just tells you that the `x` array needs to be sorted.
Note also that `make_interp_spline` does not do any smoothing. For that, use `splrep` .

Answer (score 0):

My friend's solution to this problem:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

f1 = interp1d(list(range(10)), x, kind="quadratic")
f2 = interp1d(list(range(10)), output, kind="quadratic")

xnew = f1(np.linspace(0, 8.9, 100))    
outnew = f2(np.linspace(0, 8.9, 100))




plt.plot(xnew, outnew)
plt.plot(-xnew, outnew, "b")
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).